# Calculating second order partial derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $z=f (u,v),u=\frac {x}{x^2+y^2},v=\frac {y}{x^2+y^2} $ then prove that $z_{uu}+z_{vv}=(x^2+y^2)^2 (z_{xx}+z_{yy}) $ . I have never calculated the second order partial derivatives when the function is indirectly related with the variable. I can calculate $z_x,z_y $ but dont know how to differentiate them to get $z_{xx},z_{yy }$.Thanks!

Comment: There are [many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+chain+rule+second+order+partial+derivatives) already. For example,  [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312943/multivariate-chain-rule-and-second-order-partials) should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Thanks that helped!