# Solve this multivariable function's differential equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let c a non-zero constant, solve for f in C² : $c² \frac{d² f}{dx²} = \frac{d² f}{dt²}$

They gave a hint to use the change of variable u = x+at and v = x+bt. But the problem is that i dont understand in which set f is defined at is it $\mathbb{R}^2$ or ..? and i dont see how i can make use of the hint given.

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: I did differentiate f(u,v) with respect to x and t and got $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du} +\frac{df}{dv}$ and $\frac{df}{dt} = a \frac{df}{du} + b \frac{df}{dv}$ now i differentiated again the partials with respect to x and t and got $\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2f}{du^2} + \frac{d^2 f}{dv^2}$ and $\frac{d^2 f}{dt^2} = a^2 \frac{d^2f}{du^2} + b^2 \frac{d^2 f}{dv^2}$ so if we let a=b we can easily deduce the wave equation we are questioned to solve.

Comment: That's not quite right. You're missing the mixed derivative terms in the second partials (compare with the expressions in the accepted answer to the duplicate question). And those are actually the important terms that will leave you with the transformed form of the equation, $f''_{uv}=0$, after subtraction!

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry but i dont quite understand how they did that mixed derivation of $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}$ , chain rule quite confusing for me atm

Comment: When computing $\partial^2 u/\partial t^2$, they did the same thing to $u_z$ and $u_t$ as they did to $u$ when they computed $\partial u/\partial t$ in the first step. (It's the chain rule again, but applied to the function $u_z$ and to the function $u_t$.)

Comment: See here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312943/multivariate-chain-rule-and-second-order-partials

Answer (score 0):

There is a particular choice of $a$ and $b$ which reduces your wave equation to
$$\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial u \partial v}=0.$$

Comment: can you explain further please?